# Is there an easy way to insert messages into skype?

Tags: skype

There appears to exist no API of any sorts that allows inserting messages into skype. Both Skype4COM and SkypeKit are not supported anymore.

I am interested in both

- sending messages (as if I typed them in myself)
- inserting messages into the history (bonus points if those can be synchronized to other clients)

Running the client in the background is no problem, though a solution that does not rely on it would be even better.

Comment: Whatever someone comes up with will likely be operating system specific.. so which do you require?

Comment: Pidgin hasn't come with anything better then running skype in the background, so I guess it's either difficult to reverse engineer or leads to legal issues. Perhaps you can abuse finch (the cli version of pidgin) like that, or use either pidgins api, or look at its source code to see what they do exactly.

Comment: @Skram I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: @Wrikken I'm afraid you're right, I have found nothing better than an approach like yours. I'm hoping that at least non-live data insertion is possible, though, i.e. writing into the database directly. Probably not a common use case.